# DoublyLinkedList Project: Example input 

Tags: list, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm currently working on a Doubly Linked List project in my college java course. I understand the concept of doubly linked lists, linked lists, and lists. However I'm having a lot of trouble writing my program as I'm not sure how to create the data I need to modify in my methods. Our professor usually gives us the input he will be using but didn't this time, and I can't seem to figure it out in my research.

I Suppose my main question is could anybody write some code for me to start working with and begin understanding what my methods need to be doing better?

Here is what I have so far. (Basically just the override skeleton..)

Thanks so much for any help.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class DoublyLinkedList<E> implements List<E>{

DoublyLinkedListNode header;

public static void main(String[] args) {

}
public boolean add(E e) {
    return false;
}
public void add(int index, E element) {

}
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    return false;
}
public void clear() {
    header=null;
}
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return false;
}
public E get(int index) {
    return null;
}
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    return 0;
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return header == null;
}
public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
    return 0;
}
public ListIterator<E> listIterator() {
    return null;
}
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    return false;
}
public E remove(int index) {
    return null;
}
public int size() {
    return 0;
}
public Object[] toArray() {
    return null;
}
private class DoublyLinkedListNode{
    DoublyLinkedListNode next;
    DoublyLinkedListNode last;
    E contents;
}

//extra credit
private class DoublyLinkedListItr  implements java.util.ListIterator{

    public void add(Object arg0) {

    }
    public boolean hasNext() {

        return false;
    }
    public boolean hasPrevious() {

        return false;
    }
    public Object next() {

        return null;
    }
    public int nextIndex() {

        return 0;
    }
    public Object previous() {

        return null;
    }
    public int previousIndex() {

        return 0;
    }
    public void remove() {

    }
    public void set(Object arg0) {

    }

}
public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented");
}
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented");
}
public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented");
}
public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented");
}
public E set(int index, E element) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented");
}
public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented");
}
public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented");
}
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented");
}
public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented");
}
```

}

Comment: do you really have to implement `List` interface to start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating the data here is the snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  DoublyLinkedList<String> doublyLinkedList = new DoublyLinkedList<String>();
  doublyLinkedList.add("Hello");
  doublyLinkedList.add("World");
  // If you want to store int
  DoublyLinkedList<Integer> dlli = new DoublyLinkedList<Integer>();
  dlli.add(new Integer(10));
  dlli.add(new Integer(5));
}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Create a node and store the value in it.

If header is null, have header reference your new node.

If header is not null, take the node pointed at, and as long as next is not null, take the node referenced by next. If next is null you are at the end of the list, take the next reference and have it reference your newly created node. Then take the last (I'd have called it previous) reference of your new node and have it reference your found node (end of the list).

That should get you started.